# How to pass Object ArrayList through interface?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've an interface defined as

```
public interface QueryCompleteListener {
    void onQueryCompleted(int token, ArrayList<Object1> songList);
}
```

I'm using this interface to return callback. In some callbacks I want to pass `ArrayList<Object1>` and in some cases I want to pass `ArrayList<Object2>` through the interface.

If I declare interface method as

> `void onQueryCompleted(int token, ArrayList<Object> songList)`

to pass any type of Object, it gives an error saying found Object1 required Object when I call this method by passing `ArrayList<Object1>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following:

```
<T> void onQueryCompleted(int token, List<T> songList);
```

See [Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you actually need a type variable in the method body, you can simply use:

```
void onQueryCompleted(int token, List<?> songList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard is the way to go but you probably want some form of control over what type of object you are using.

Just make the custom classes (Object1, Object2, ...) implements a custom interface (CustomSuperInterface) and declare the collection like this

```
void onQueryCompleted(int token, List<? extends CustomSuperInterface> songList);
```